# Can a Collections.shuffle be considered equivalent to a series of Randoms?

Tags: java, random

Following this question: [Shuffling numbers in a map and selecting one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881763/generate-random-number-from-only-three-number/)

Say you need to select a series of integers randomly from a `List`. Could a `Collections.shuffle` be considered as equivalent to repeatedly using [`Random#nextInt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt)?

I'm not familiar with how shuffle is implemented and whether they could be seen as truly equivalent from a mathematical point of view (permutations). The link below does insist on the importance of using a single `Random` object.

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62

P.S: I'm aware that `Collections.shuffle` adds an operation in that it actually reorganizes content. It's the result I'm interested in.

Edit: Found this question on SO detailing the shuffle method as using what's called a Fisher-Yates shuffle: [Java's Collections.shuffle is doing what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249520/javas-collections-shuffle-is-doing-what)

Comment: What do you mean by *equivalent*? That both return the exact same sequence? That both return values in the same range? That both probability distribution functions are the same?

Comment: Equivalent in the same way that algorithm A would be equivalent to algorithm B if they produced the exact same fixed results. Edit: Equivalent from the point of view of probability distribution as you say.

Comment: Just remember that Random#nextInt isn't really random anyway... it is pseudo-random, therefore deterministic. The same goes for `shuffle`.

Comment: You're right to point that out. There's some interesting information on the topic in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438155/how-to-check-if-a-function-really-gives-a-random-result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if using `Collections.shuffle` and then using the resulting list of randomly-ordered numbers is equivalent to picking them one by one by using `Random`, the answer is no. The latter will quite likely return you the same index twice, which will result in duplicates.

Comment: Ok. Say the algorithm using Random includes a step where the randomly selected index is removed. Could they be considered equivalent then? I've updated the question with a relevant link from SO.

Comment: For a limited amount of operations (collection's size), yes. Until the collection runs out of elements.

Comment: @James: For all intents and purposes, yes, that would make them equivalent. However removing indexes will likely not be as efficient as `Collections.shuffle`, which does the whole thing in-place (as long as the collection supports quick indexed access)